# Attendees being able to join Meet without permission. Google Calendar API

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api, google-meet

I Am using the Google Calender API to generate a Google Meet link, my problem is that the attendees need the host permission to access the Meet, I tried setting them as organizers but it doesnt seems to do anything, is there any parameter or something I can add so they can join whenever they want without needing permission?

```
const event = {
          summary: "Meet",
          description: `meeting `,
          start: {
            dateTime: startingTime,
          },
          end: {
            dateTime: endingTime,
          },
          conferenceData: {
            createRequest: {
                requestId: random,
                conferenceSolutionKey: { type: "hangoutsMeet" },
            },
        },
        params: {
          sendNotifications: true
          },
          
          attendees: [
            {
              email: EmailOne,
            organizer: true},
            { email: EmailTwo,
            organizer: true},
          ],
        };
  
        const response = calendar.events.insert({
              calendarId: calendarId,
              resource: event,
              conferenceDataVersion: 1
          });
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

### Unfortunately currently guests cannot join without permission Google Meets created programmatically

- By default the event creator is the only organizer
- An event cannot have more than one organizer
- `organizer`is a read-only property, you cannot modify it
- The problem you encounter is that when creating events programmatically the event invitees do not automatically become Google Meet invitees and thus, are not allowed to join without approval. A feature request to change this behavior has already been [filed](https://issuetracker.google.com/199778896) on Google's Issue Tracker
- What you probably actually want to do when trying to set guests to event organizers is to make them [Co-Hosts](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2022/04/assign-cohosts-configure-host-controls-in-calendar.html#:%7E:text=End%20users%3A%20To%20configure%20host,Host%20controls%20or%20Co%2Dhosts)
- Unfortunately, this is currently not possible via API neither, but has also already been [requested](https://issuetracker.google.com/208860809)
- As of now, all you can do is to "star" the respective feture requests to increase visibility and hopefully accelerate implementation

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue at our client. The work around we found was that if you add the event creator to the attendees list and enable [the following feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRcYc.png) on the organisation level

Any account from within the organisation can join the meeting without approval. External accounts however still need permission to join the meet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).