# Configuring Google.Calendar.Apis to Generate Google Meet Links for Attendees to Join Without Prompt, while Others Require Permission,How to Implement?

Tags: c#, .net, google-calendar-api

I'm utilizing the Google.Calendar.Apis library to generate Google Meet links programmatically. My goal is to set up the meetings in a way that attendees with specified email addresses can join directly without being prompted, while others are required to request permission to join.

I've been able to successfully generate the Google Meet links using the library, but I'm struggling to find a way to configure the permissions for attendees appropriately.

Is there a specific parameter or setting within the Google.Calendar.Apis library that allows for this level of customization? Alternatively, would it require integration with Google Meet API or other methods to achieve this functionality?

Any insights or examples on how to implement this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I've attempted to configure the event creation using the Google.Calendar.Apis library in .NET. Specifically, I've set up the event with the required attendees and included the Google Meet link in the conferenceData section of the event. However, regardless of the settings I've tried, all attendees, including those explicitly listed in the event, are being prompted to join the meeting.

I expected that by setting the response status of the attendees to 'accepted' and including the Google Meet link, those attendees would be able to join the meeting directly without being asked to join. For other non-listed attendees, I anticipated they would need to request permission to join.

Unfortunately, this approach hasn't yielded the desired outcome, and I'm unsure of what additional steps or configurations are needed to achieve this functionality.

Comment: To clarify, the statement that `all attendees, including those explicitly listed in the event, are being prompted to join the meeting` means that everyone, even those invited to the event, is being asked to be accepted by the meeting organizer. Would that be correct?

Comment: i want all people that invited join to meeting without prompt  @Saddles

Comment: Gotcha. I found this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73118988) having a similar issue as yours, and from what I see, it's expected that users who join Google Meet sessions created programmatically, such as with the Google Calendar API, are prompted to join the event because it's a feature that hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: The answer also states that Google's already aware of this matter, so a `+1` to it would tell them that you're impacted by the issue. This is the link for the feature request: [Extend Calendar API to add people to a Google Meet.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/199778896)